# segmentation fault (core dumped) in simple assignment

Tags: c, malloc, typedef, freebsd

I'm using c and wrote this code on a freeBSD system.

```
///// defines /////

#define CPUCORES                2
#define THREADAMOUNT            CPUCORES - 1
#define nullptr                 NULL

///// typedefs /////

typedef enum BOOL_e
{
    e_FALSE = 0,
    e_TRUE = 1
}BOOL_t;

typedef struct NewClient_s
{
int sdNewClient;
struct sockaddr sdinClientIp;
socklen_t sdlenIPsize;
}NewClient_t;

typedef struct ClientThreadArg_s
{
    int iInternID;
    NewClient_t sIncommingClient;
    BOOL_t bHasKillSig;
    BOOL_t bIsShutdown;
}ClientThreadArg_t;

//------------------------------------ imagin this is the main

    ClientThreadArg_t *spListOfArguments;
    size_t sizeIndexI;
    spListOfArguments = (ClientThreadArg_t *) malloc (THREADAMOUNT * sizeof     (ClientThreadArg_t));   



for (sizeIndexI = 0; sizeIndexI < THREADAMOUNT; sizeIndexI++)
{   
    spListOfArguments[sizeIndexI].bHasKillSig = e_TRUE;//Heres the error....
}
```

This is the code snippet which I figured out is responsible for the error, but I don't understand why. I tried allocating mem for the double space as required and I still got the error. As I allocated for 100 elements it appeared to be enough... I didn't had the error anymore. The sizeof ClientThreadArg_t is as suggested 36 and the loop just runnes 1 time. So, what I'm doing wrong in the way I'm allocating the memory for that structure?

Comment: Are you sure (ie: checked with a debugger) that this is the point where the error is or you just guessed ?

Comment: `#define nullptr NULL` - Poor Man's C++0x?

Comment: well i commented out almost the whole code there isnt much more as this snippet currently. whenn im commenting out this line, all is running well. When i make the allocated memory pretty big, all is running well too, and this is the only line where currently the pointer is used, and this pointer is in the current code the only pointer which is working with allocated memory. No i used not a debugger yet, but afaik, my tests are responsible enough to say its not just a guess.

Comment: did you check to make sure taht malloc isnt returning null?

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference, but try sizeof(struct ClientThreadArg_s) instead of ClientThreadArg_t

Comment: nope, nullptr is used in C11 too, but currently there is no compiler for it, i just use this in all my code, so i later dont have to change it

Comment: Install [`valgrind`](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Valgrind), and use it against your code to see what errors it reports.

Comment: oh god damn this is so sad.... i Realy forgot to check for malloc is returning zero... yip it does return zero and i was not catching this. but so now im asking my self: WHY it is returning NULL when im allocating less then THREADAMOUNT < 100???

Comment: Because you're out of memory. Make sure your ulimts are set properly.

Try ulimit -v unlimited

Comment: but when im doing malloc (100 * X) im getting returned a valid area, when i do malloc (1 * X) it returns NULL, ok i will try it, but doesn't sound like the solution for me yet.

Comment: That's weird, you probably have some serious fragmentation going on. What doesn't make sense is that you can get 100*x but malloc wont carve out a 1*X from its free list.

Comment: @Zaibis: please quote the section of the ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard where `nullptr` is defined.  My search of the PDF from ANSI didn't find it.

Comment: If it weren't that 'too localized' is no longer a valid close reason, I'd close this as too localized.  It is hard to work out which other questions are close-to-duplicates; it is a valid question, but has limited application to people visiting the site in future (not least because the actual issues are "What are the perils of not parenthesizing macros properly" and "What are the perils of not checking memory allocation is successful" rather than anything else).

Comment: @Scotty Well the point was: in the first try i did 2 * THREADAMOUNT the second try was THRADAMOUNT * 100 .... As long i thought the defines are ok, that would had make no difference... but my fault was the wrong use of the defines....

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, well i checked it out too, and your right, i jsut mixed something up in my mind, its not C11 its jsut the c++ standard... im going to change it in my codes, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to tell when I can't run your code, but from the look of it, it might be here

```
 spListOfArguments = malloc (THREADAMOUNT * sizeof(ClientThreadArg_t));
```

Notice that THREADAMOUNT is defined as `CPUCORES - 1` which is `2 - 1`

What that means is that you would be getting

```
 spListOfArguments = malloc (2 - 1 * sizeof(ClientThreadArg_t));
```

and thus you would be mallocing a negative number which would return null

Comment: oh hell yeah... sounds simple for me, so i would have to #define THREADAMOUNT (CPUCORES - 1) right?

Comment: Yup! That should fix the problem. That is one of the dangers of using defines

Comment: remove the damn casts from malloc()!

Comment: Good catch, Synderesis.

Comment: On FreeBSD, you can use `sysctl(3)` to check the actual numbers of cores.